# npm: missing transitive dependencies in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-link

I have two local npm projects, `A` and `B`.
Let's say `A` depends on `react` and has it listed as a dependency in the `package.json` file. I use `npm link` to make `A` available for `B`.

`B` depends on `A` and `react`. I use `npm link A` to use the local version of `A`. However, as I know that `A` already depends on `react`, I do not include `react` in my `package.json` file of `B`.
When I call `npm install` I would expect npm to include transitive dependencies in the `node_modules` folder. However, I cannot find `react` in it nor can I use it in `B`'s code as long as I don't include the transitive dependency in `B`'s own `package.json` file.

When I include other modules like `react`, I also get transitive dependencies like `fbjs` or `encoding` resolved into my `node_modules` folder.

So, where is the mistake? / Why are the dependencies of `A` not included in `B`'s `node_modules` folder?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same behaviour with npm 5.6. After a downgrade of npm to 4.6 version, "npm install" ran right. After this I figured out the problem was a package-lock.json committed by a teammates of mine and not synchronized to package.json

Comment: package-lock.json did not work for me.. still not working